# Ubuntu 12.04 wired connection doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, networking, dhcp, wired

I just installed Ubuntu again after a few months of using Windows.

At first, I tried to install it by using an .ISO file; but, I got stuck at 43% on the partitioner, so I figured out I should use the Wubi installer.

So, I installed Ubuntu 12.04, rebooted my PC, and went on to Ubuntu.

Everything was working fine, except the internet connection.

It was stuck trying to connect to Wired Ethernet, but it didn't work. When I changed from DHCP to manual and entered an IP- address. It connected; but, I still couldn't use internet and it wouldn't enter any sites.

I've searched all over internet and tried different solutions, but none of them is working for me. I've had Ubuntu installed on the same computer before, and then it worked just fine, but not this time.

`ifconfig` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:60:00:c4:4c:b4  
      inet6 addr: fe80::ca60:ff:fec4:4cb4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3090 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2340549 (2.3 MB)  TX bytes:334975 (334.9 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7300000-f7320000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:58956 (58.9 KB)  TX bytes:58956 (58.9 KB)
```

Network Manager Tool output:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connecting

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired

  Driver:            e1000e

  State:             connecting (getting IP configuration)

  Default:           no

  HW Address:        C8:60:00:C4:4C:B4


  Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes

Speed:           100 Mb/s

Wired Properties

Carrier:         on
```

`route -n` output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

`ping` output:

```
ping 
connect: Network is unreachable
```

When I try to configure the `/etc/network` interface file to set DHCP, my network tab says:
`Device not managed`. I have also tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but it still wont work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could I strongly recommend you to NOT connect a device that hasn't gotten any updates in the last 4 Years

Answer (score 0):

To get networkmanager to manage this interface, try this in a terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Change the line 'managed=false' to 'managed=true'

Save, then in the same terminal we need to restart the network manager.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

That should clear it up for you.

Comment: It didn't work.. Still trying to connect, but it won't